# Arduino IRsend: no matching function for call to IRsend::send

Tags: arduino, infrared

Trying to send an NEC infrared code through Arduino but getting error message: 
exit status 1
no matching function for call to `IRsend:send(long int, int)`

```
#include <IRLib.h>

IRsend remote;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.read() != -1) {
    //send a code every time a character is received from the serial port
    //Candle Remote On
    remote.send(0xFF30CF, 32);
  }
}
```

Getting the following error message

Answer (score 0):

IRSend's send method is declared as:

```
void send(IRTYPES Type, unsigned long data, unsigned int data2);
```

which has 3 arguments (parameters) and you are only passing it two. Pass the needed parameters.

The error says that there is not an overloaded method available with that arguments list.

Comment: I added the first parameter, NEC, and now I am getting a compiling error. It sounds like there are multiple definitions of everything. IRLib.cpp is defined in more than one place. Will investigate. Thanks, @Blurry Sterk

Comment: If you have not done it yet then I do propose that you open the header file (.h) for the library and have a look at the declarations of the methods. They will give you an indication of what is expected. Sometimes documentation or examples on websites are out of date.